# Exclude file types expect txt files in C

Tags: c

Hello and Happy new Year ,

I have to accept juste txt files in my C programme ,

I don't have any idea to how to made it .. any ideas?

And I don't know if text file contain Header or something which characterize it..

PS: I'm using Ubuntu so file extension is not seen.

Thank you

Comment: please post the code that is giving you trouble.

Comment: can you show some code which you've already tried and din't work?

Comment: why - 10 haha,  i havn't yet a code i have just loaded a text file using  a pointer and fopen , but i want to denny any other files type

Answer (score 0):

In a Linux environment, I would personally go with `libmagic`, which is the core of the utility program `file`. The purpose of this library is to do exactly what you are trying to accomplish: identify the type of a file based on it content.

Example usage would look like this.

```
/* identify.c */

#define _POSIX_SOURCE /* required for fileno() */

#include <magic.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *description;
    magic_t cookie;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cookie = magic_open(MAGIC_NONE);

    if(cookie == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot initialize library\n");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if( magic_load(cookie, NULL) != 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot load database : %s\n",
                                            magic_error(cookie));
        magic_close(cookie);
        fclose(fp);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    description = magic_descriptor(cookie, fileno(fp));
    printf("%s\n", description);

    magic_close(cookie);
    fclose(fp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Name this source file `identify.c`, create a text file name `example.txt` with some content in the same directory, and compile with:

gcc -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -lmagic -o identify identify.c

Then run it.

./identify

And you get something like this printed:

```
UTF-8 Unicode text
```

This library can be used in a few different ways, so you should probably have a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic). For example, you can get a MIME type instead of a description like the one above.

The `file` package of which libmagic is a part is probably already installed on your machine. However, if you are using a distribution such as RHEL of CentOS that splits development headers into a separate package, make sure you have `file-devel` installed.